# C++ Efficient interpolation of a std::vector

Tags: c++, sorting, interpolation, std, stdvector

I need to find the value of a function given its unknown by interpolation. The problem is that the one I created is way too inefficient.

Firstly, I read a data file that contains both y=g(T) and T, but in discrete form. And I store their values in a `std::vector<double>`.

After this, I convert T (`std::vector<double> Tgdat`) to x (`std::vector<double> xgdat`). This will be the x-axis that will accompany the y-axis, (`std::vector<double> gdat`).

Then, I create a function to interpolate my vector `std::vector<double> gdat`, so that, given some x (which its value is in between two elements of the vector `std::vector<double> xgdat`), the program can spit some value for g(x). This function receives the vectors by reference, not because I want to modify them (that's why I also pass them as `const`), but so that the computer doesn't have to create copies of it.

```
double geffx (double x, const std::vector<double> &gdat, const std::vector<double> &xgdat)
{
  //Local variables
  double g;
  int k,l;

  //Find the index of the element of xgdat that is nearest to x
  auto i = min_element(xgdat.begin(), xgdat.end(),
      [x] (double a, double b)
      {
          return abs(x-a)<abs(x-b);
      });
  k = std::distance(xgdat.begin(), i); //Nearest index

  //Find the index of the element of xgdat that is nearest to x
  //and it is not the same index as before
  auto j = min_element(xgdat.begin(), xgdat.end(),
      [x,&xgdat,k] (double a, double b)
      {
          if (a!=xgdat[k]) return abs(x-a)<abs(x-b);
          else return false;
      });
  l = std::distance(xgdat.begin(), j); //Second nearest index

  //Interpolation:
  if(xgdat[k]<xgdat[l]) 
      g = gdat[k]+(x-xgdat[k])*(gdat[l]-gdat[k])/(xgdat[l]-xgdat[k]);
  else 
      g = gdat[l]+(x-xgdat[l])*(gdat[k]-gdat[l])/(xgdat[k]-xgdat[l]);

  return g;
}
```

This seems to be highly inefficient, but I can't wrap my head around something that solves this same problem but in a more efficient way. I've tried the `const` thing and also passing by reference, but I guess the big problem is the `min_element()` function/method, and maybe it also has to do with the if-else at the end to return the value of g.

---

Edit: Extra info

I'm using `g++` as the compiler, the number of elements is 275.

Since this function is part of an EDO solver it's called in every step (1e4 steps) multiple times until it converges. I need 4 interpolators which are called more than once each for its evaluation, so I would say that the function needs to be accessed more than 1e6 times.

Back when I substituted g(x) with a constant (no need of interpolators) the execution time was around 1-10 seconds. Now it's 45 mins - 1 hour. (very bad, I know, that's why I need help)

Comment: There is missing information, such as compiler used, whether you are running an optimized build or "debug" build, the typical number of elements in the vector, and actual timing statistics.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the info. However, I don't know what you mean by "optimized build" vs "debug build", I just write the typical ```g++ name.cpp -o name``` and then run it by writing ```.\name``` in the terminal.

Comment: binary search, since the data is sorted? (if it isn't, sort it first)

Comment: It's only sorted if the function is monotonic, which is not guaranteed.  It goes up and down repeatedly, in general.

Comment: @AdriánDavid you did not give it any optimization flags, so you will have very slow code!  There's your problem, I think.  Try adding `-O2` to that.   Assuming that debug info is included by default with g++, this is a "debug build".

Comment: @JDługosz you only need x to be sorted, no need for a monotonic function...

Comment: I think the idea is that if `xgdat` is sorted by `x`, you can use a binary search to find the minimum closest to the argument `x`.

Comment: Oh, OK; I thought he was doing the opposite.  In that case, why does he need the result vector at all?  Just evaluate the function at the two needed points.

Comment: It can also help to evaluate for several values at the same time. Again, sort, and do something similar to merging to find the position of all the points.

Comment: How often does the data file change?  If you do a million lookups on one function, then change the function, then a lot more preprocessing (sorting, building balanced trees, etc) can make sense.  If the function changes for each of the million lookups, preprocessing won't be amortized and is hurting you.

Comment: @BenVoigt the data file doesn't change, it is readed once in another function and then closed. I just use the ```std::vector```s as constant vectors, they don't change. They have to be accessed to compare their elements with a given ```x``` and to interpolate.

Comment: @JohnBayko yes, ```xgdat``` is sorted in ascending/descending order of x. I've used ```std::sort()``` to find the closest to x before. However this was useless, I need the index, because I need to use it in order to use ```gdat[k]``` in the interpolation.

Comment: @AdriánDavid: You maintain the x->G(x) pairings when you sort.  Typically this is done by sorting an array of `struct { double x, y; }` (comparing x during sort) instead of separately sorting an array of x and an array of y.  A suitable C++ type would be `std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>`.  If after sorting you want to separate x and G(x) into two separate arrays go ahead.

Comment: Yet another approach is to store `x, G(x), g'(x)` so you don't have to lookup two elements and do a division to get slope, it's stored right there in the lookup table.

Comment: @JDługosz I only have one point, ```x```, in which I evaluate the function. I need g(x), but the simplest way I can get it is through linear interpolation (comparing with the 2 points closest to x in ```xgdat```). Also, I'm not aware of using any result vector, I'm using them as constant vectors, they don't change in any way and don't give me any result.

Comment: @BenVoigt ```xgdat``` is already sorted. g(x) is entangled to x, it is not necessarily an ascending or descending function, it can be both, so ```gdat``` is not sorted. Also, where is g'(x) stored? What is what you call "the lookup table" in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose `min_element`, lose the absolute distance comparison.  It's a convex transformation which can be searched efficiently, but not by any function that exists in the C++ standard library.

You don't want the two closest points anyway, you want to bracket your evaluation above and below.  (The only case where "closest two" always gives a bracketing pair is when the samples are uniformly spaced, and if that's true you don't need a search at all, you can calculate the index directly using the spacing interval).

Use `lower_bound` to do an efficient binary search in the sorted array for the `x` you care about.  That's one side of your bracket, the other index is one lower.

In the end the top portion of your code will look something like:

```
//Find the index of the element of xgdat that is nearest-above to x
auto i = lower_bound(xgdat.begin(), xgdat.end(), x); 
//If the vector values are in decreasing order use:
//auto i = lower_bound(xgdat.rbegin(), xgdat.rend(), x);
k = i - xgdat.begin(); //Nearest index
if (i == xgdat.end())
  --k;  // extrapolating above
else if (*i == x)
  return gdat[k];

l = k? k - 1: 1; //nearest-below index, except when extrapolating downward

// proceed with linear interpolation/extrapolation using l and k
```

Comment: ```lower_bound()``` only seems to work if ```xgdat``` is sorted in ascending order, not in descending order, which is the case sometimes. ```i``` always points to the first element if it is in descending order.

Comment: @AdriEscañuela: The iterators have to find the data in ascending order.  If your vector is in descending order, use `lower_bound(xgdat.rbegin(), xgdat.rend(), x);`

Comment: @AdriEscañuela: Any rough idea on how much faster this might have made your solver?

Comment: It was being slowed down because of some errors in the jacobian of the EDO solver. Now it's solved in a fraction of a second, same as before when I setted g(x)=constant. The now-correct program also runs really fast with the implementation I gave in my question as well, but I accepted your solution because ```min_element()``` complexity grows as $O(n)$ whilst ```lower_bound()``` as $O(log_2(n))$ (binary sort is better). In my program it is not noticeable at all, but someone might find your solution very helpful.

Comment: I think k should be: k = i - xgdat.begin();  And maybe better, k = std::distance(xgdat.begin(),i);

Comment: @Tyson: Yeah that order was backwards.  But `std::distance` is a bad idea.  You don't want to use the binary-search approach on a container without random access.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips on the code:

Declare variables where needed, not all at the top.

```
if(xgdat[k]<xgdat[l]) 
      g = gdat[k]+(x-xgdat[k])*(gdat[l]-gdat[k])/(xgdat[l]-xgdat[k]);
  else 
      g = gdat[l]+(x-xgdat[l])*(gdat[k]-gdat[l])/(xgdat[k]-xgdat[l]);
```

It looks like those two lines are the same except for swapping k and l.  So don't duplicate the line:  just swap k and l!

```
if(xgdat[k]>=xgdat[l]) std::swap(k,l);
```

and `g` is only used right here?  Why did you declare it way up at the top of the function?  It's not needed at all now:

```
return gdat[k]+(x-xgdat[k])*(gdat[l]-gdat[k])/(xgdat[l]-xgdat[k]);
```

You're going to some trouble to get "index positions" back out after calling standard algorithms that work with iterators.  You should just use iterators.

None of that is overall efficiency though.